# Loading an external view controller, from a button click on another view controller

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller, camera

Im officially getting annoyed with objective-c and xcode now. Programming in PHP and Java is so much easier haha.

Anyway I could do with some help.

I have created a tab bar application with three tab items for the iPhone, on one of the items it loads a nib named mapView, this contains a button that I want to use to load up another nib named OverlayViewController.

Ive been following this tutorial [this tutorial](http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=821#comment-256)
to create a camera overlay. I understand how it works, but I don't understand how to run the view controller from a button or direct from the tab bar. I can only get the overlay to work if I load it like in the example on application launch in the app delegate. If I try and load it from the tab bar item I just get a grey screen, looks like the blank view controller is loaded and the code hasnt been run to show the overlay.

If anyone can suggest how I would go about loading the overlay from the button click, or even direct from the tab bar item I would be really grateful.

Thanks Alex

p.s. [Heres the link to the project if you wish to view the files](http://www.alexapps.co.uk/Files/NavUniApp.zip)

Answer (score 0):

@AlexApps I took a look through your project and have several pieces of feedback.

I think before you get too into trying to get the OverlayViewController working you should back up a bit and give some of the Apple docs a read, especially the [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH1-SW1). The Apple docs are for the most part well written and should help you gain a better understanding of views and view controllers than what is evident in your code.

Another suggestion is to grab some of the freely available source code from a book such as [Beginning iPhone Programming](http://apress.com/book/downloadfile/4679) which has a good example of how to lay out a tabBarController based app. I am sure there are other good samples out there that will show you how to organize your views and view controllers to load them into the different tabs.

I think that if you follow this advice that by the time you have restructured your app by what you learn you will have less problem doing what you are trying to do.

BTW, you may want to consider using a NavigationViewController for what you are trying to do with loading the OverlayViewController with a button press but take a few hours, slow down and do some focused reading. It will make a world of difference. Then if you have more specific questions, Stack Overflow (and Google) are your friends.

One last tip, you do not need to put IBOutlet in your instance variables AND in your properties, just one or the other, and really, you don't even need the instance variables at all anymore. I usually just use properties for everything.

Answer (score 0):

First import uiviewcontroller class in frist page like below:

```
#import "page2viewcontroller.h"
```

on button click event code below:

```
page2viewcontroller *page2 =[page2viewcontroller alloc] ;
[self presentModalViewController:page2 animated:NO];
[page2 release];
```

after back page2viewcontroller to page1viewcontroller same as like below:

```
 #import "page1viewcontroller.h"
```

on backbutton click event code below:

```
page1viewcontroller *page1 =[page2viewcontroller alloc] ;
[self presentModalViewController:page1 animated:NO];
[page1 release];
```

That's all....!

Answer (score 0):

I have done it with storyboard and the solution is to create a segue between the tab bar view controller and the view controller you want to load, then you have to put an identifier to that segue. Finally, in the method called when the button is pressed you have to put this:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueId" sender:sender];
```

I have done it right now and it works perfect!